# VB6: create IHTMLElementCollection from scratch

Tags: html, vb6

I have a HTML document and want to return only certain elements from it as `IHTMLElementCollection`. For example, there's a table, and i want to put all table rows with a certain class name into the collection. Any ideas if it's possible?

Is it possible to create an `IHTMLElementCollection` from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any api to create a new HtmlElementCollection. It is returned from the HtmlDocument object with methods like getElementsByName and GetElementsByTagName. Maybe you can modify one of those returned collections, but I doubt it.

Possible alternatives: Perhaps create your own container class and return it? Or an regular vb6 collection or array?